How can I return the original selfie taken in night mode with a 3-second wait?
I took a selfie in night mode iPhone 13 with iOS 17.5.1.
This required a 3-second wait for the best photo quality (it was automatically turned on). As a result, this photo turned out to be completely blurred, since the phone was not held motionless. While the photo was just taken, I saw a well-taken photo, and later in the gallery it became smudged.
Can I return this photo to the state when it was just taken?

On which iOS and which camera are you using? iPad or iPhone or Mac camera - I'm assuming you're using an iPhone, but you didn't really document things carefully other than stating the desire to find something you saw on screen and now can't locate.

I took a selfie on an iPhone 13 with iOS 17.5.1
